# Fitting truncated sample to normal distribution with unknown mean & variance

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

I have data that is somehow truncated. It is a list of log best performances from events, where different events have different cutoff times.

How could it be possible to find the unknown mean and unknown variance of the true normal distribution? I suppose as a start I would need to use a sample unaffected by the cutoff times of the events. It may still be that there is less data closer to the cutoff times, as athletes risking to miss the cutoff may not even participate in the first place.

But then the difficult part... Both the mean & variance of the true normal distribution are unknown. How can I do a possible fit of the sample data to the unknown normal distribution?

These are charts of (almost) all data, as well as the left tail zoomed in, with the blue line just representing a visual estimate of the normal distribution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you you want to fit a normal distribution to a mixture of (possibly non-normal) distributions? (It's clear from the first graph that each event, or type of event, has its own distribution.)

Comment: The graphs are top lists of all performances during five years. The saw issue comes from every hour as a goal for many to go below. So it's just one distribution of all recorded performances during a certain time period.

Comment: And the reason I want to find the mean and variance of the "invisible parent distribution" is to find the probability of a certain time being broken, i.e. I need the PDF of the prior distribution to get an accurate estimate of the posterior distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Your data is has structure incl. performances across years and events, possibly by some of the same athletes and you would need to model that structure to get reasoble probability estimates. (And also categories of athletes by ability if I understand the comment about "every hour as a goal to go below".) I don't think there is an underlying true normal distribution for this dataset. I would suggest that it would be easier to get on point advice if you provide much more detailed description of the data.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a separate post with much more details about what I'm trying to achieve. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626146/develop-a-model-for-theoretical-best-performances-at-different-ultra-running-dis